# Interpolation Inequality's Proof

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega \subseteq R^{n}$ bounded domain. I need to prove that for $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$: 
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\leq \|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\|\Delta u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}
\end{equation}
I know that I should prove it for a $u\in C^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ and then use the Global Approximation Theorem with smooth functions to extend $u\in C^{2}_{0}(\Omega)$ to $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. Also, I know the following expression could be useful: 
\begin{equation}
\Delta(\frac{u^{2}}{2})=|\nabla u|^{2}+u\Delta u   
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use integration by parts in each coordinate direction to write the Left hand side as the integral of u times the Laplacian of u. Then apply Cauchy- Schwarz.